# What is wrong with this syntax? how can i use $.get method inside prepend function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
for(var i=1; i<=num_rows; i++)
{
    $('#question-board').prepend('<div id=myID'+i' class=abc>'+ $.get("forum-data-retrieve.php", {q:i}); +'</div> <hr>');
}
```

Comment: Besides syntax, I would suggest wrapping line on logical points to help understanding. The convention is to keep lines of code within 80 symbols. You can wrap after dot, or after opening parenthesis, for example.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is an async method, so you can't just inline it. You'll have to wait for the results to be able to process them.

You could try something like the following:

```
for(var i=1; i<=num_rows; i++)
{
    $.get("forum-data-retrieve.php", {q:i}, function(data) {
        $('#question-board').prepend('<div id=myID' + i + ' class=abc>' + data + '</div><hr>');
    });
}
```